I am getting errors during deployment of the following code : Please help
Errors :

@Override specified for non-overriding method: void
VehicleInventoryExtractScheduler.rescheduleJob() (line:45)
Invalid type: RepeatScheduler (line:11)

public with sharing class VehicleInventoryExtractScheduler extends RepeatScheduler implements Schedulable {
    private static final String CDK_INTEGRATION_SETTING_DEVELOPER_NAME = 'Integration_Setting';
    private static final String VEHICLE_INVENTORY_EXTRACT_BATCH_NAME = 'Vehicle Inventory Extract';
    private static final String VEHICLE_INVENTORY_EXTRACT_BATCH_TEST_NAME = 'Vehicle Inventory Extract Test';
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        Database.executeBatch(new CDKPIPInventoryVehicleBatch(null),1); //Call PIP Batch JOb Here
        findAndAbortJob((!Test.isRunningTest()) ? VEHICLE_INVENTORY_EXTRACT_BATCH_NAME : VEHICLE_INVENTORY_EXTRACT_BATCH_TEST_NAME);
    }
    protected override void rescheduleJob(){
        CDK_Integration_Setting__mdt setting
            = CDK_Integration_Setting__mdt.getInstance(CDK_INTEGRATION_SETTING_DEVELOPER_NAME);
    
        System.schedule(
            (!Test.isRunningTest()) ? VEHICLE_INVENTORY_EXTRACT_BATCH_NAME : VEHICLE_INVENTORY_EXTRACT_BATCH_TEST_NAME,
            PIPRepeatSchedulerUtility.generateCRONExpresionForPIP(setting.Vehicle_Inventory_Extract_Frequency__c, setting.Vehicle_Inventory_Extract_Min_Frequency__c),
            new VehicleInventoryExtractScheduler()
        );
    }
}

public abstract inherited sharing class RepeatScheduler {
    protected virtual void findAndAbortJob(String jobName) {
        List<CronTrigger> cronTriggers = [SELECT Id FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.Name = :jobName];
        if (cronTriggers.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
    
        try {
            System.abortJob(cronTriggers[0].Id);
            rescheduleJob();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    protected abstract void rescheduleJob();
}


Make sure you actually deployed RepeatScheduler to the (same) org (as the other class). The problem is not in the presented code. In case of doubt, find the class under Setup - Custom Code - Apex Classes.
